# How to restore contents of recycling bin to different folder AND retaining original folder structure

Tags: windows, file-management, path, restore, recycle-bin

**Problem:**

After deleting lots of sets of files with the same name to recycle bin over time, one can lose track of what they have deleted and want to review them.

It seems that Windows recycling bin flattens the folder structure when the user attempts to move the files out of the recycling bin. Which means that when doing this for files of the same name but different path, the process will be stopped by successive Windows dialogs saying file already exists.

**Required Solutions:**

- Retain as much of the file's folder path as possible when restoring, so that files of same names get written to such different folder paths so that Windows won't report that file already exists.
- Define a new, ordinary folder location for deleted files which isn't the Recycling Bin and therefore wouldn't have its flattening of file paths limitation.

**Research done already (so suprised someone else hasn't come across this issue, it seems)**

- [Restore recycle bin to specified location in lieu of original
  location?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-files/restore-recycle-to-specified-location-in-lieu-of/6ba2f037-f69d-48a3-81b7-d440b083aa7a) - Unsatisfactory - doesn't provide solution required,
  will encounter the file exists dialog when moving the files
- [How to restore file from the Recycle Bin to a specific location?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29136926/227926) Encouraging but I would need to "build" this code and package it into an executable program, which I could do, but would prefer not to
  do that.
- [superuser.com search yielded zero results as of 2020-11-20 2340 GMT:
  "We couldn't find anything for restore recycle bin to different
  folder retaining folder structure"](https://superuser.com/search?q=restore%20recycle%20bin%20to%20different%20folder%20retaining%20folder%20structure)

**Background**

I'm using [InSync Google Drive Client](https://insynchq.com) to sync files from Google Drive.  When I re-org the structure or delete a lot of files, particulatly duplicates, over time, they end up in the local machine's recycling bin.  This is proving hard to manage and be confident about what I'm deleting because I can't get the files out to a different location than the original to check over. I end up having to cut bunches of files in several goes, creating a separate restore folder each time to avoid the file already exists.  Then I use MindGems Fast Duplicate File Finder and/or Scooter Software's Beyond Compare to compare the files against a master to be sure I'm deleting duplicates.

By the way - NO affiliation whatsoever with any of the mentioned companies or their products.

Comment: Let this be a lesson as to why not to use the Trash as a filing system. If you need to review before final discard, use another location. I sympathise with your situation, but it is of your own making, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you. it is not me directly deleting files to trash.  The InSync Google Drive client does it, for the 2 reasons outlined in the "Background".  The reasoning behind why it deletes files to trash when re-orging the structure is not clear to me.  This problem question I have may have more than one lead, that's why I'm asking it here to explore solutions as well as discussing on InSyncHQ.com's forums as well.

Comment: Ah, OK - I hadn't actually realised it was the sync app doing it (my bad, first coffee;) That seems a kind of 'between two stools' structure; I'd normally expect something like that to actually appear to overwrite previous versions but keep a history in case you change your mind. The way it's doing it is probably the worst of both worlds. I'd be looking for a better app.

Comment: +1 upvote x 2 for both your comments; I really appreciate your time. I think I'm making some progress managing the situation: I backup to external hard drive storage and use BD-Rs / BD-REs as well. Coupled with MindGems Fast Duplicate File Finder and Scooter Software's Beyond Compare I can clean up duplicate files to help me structure my filing organisation effectively.

Comment: The InSync app is better than Google's own Backup and Restore app in that it discovers the filing structure much more rapidly.  Apart from the oddity as to how it decides to delete a file, it seems to not scale very well to large amounts of files when it is in the process of syncing. Nor does Google's own.  I'm not aware of any other client, so InSync seems to be the best I've got.

Comment: Update. Google Drive desktop client has been changed by them to appear as a drive letter, resembling a network drive. There is an option to make files (and folders, I think) available offline. This development may alter how this question is asked and answered and I will review it later. Thank you!